# Can I cancel SSH (after using it to browse) without logging out?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, osx

I've used the command `ssh -D 8080 -f -C -q -N user@IP` to SSH into a VPS and set it to browse in the SOCKS proxy settings in System Preferences (on my Mac).

How do I cancel the SSH session (and browse normally) without having to log out?

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> 'cancels' certain commands that are running, but once I do the `ssh -D` it immediately logs out of the VPS.

Also, unrelated question: Does logging out cancel the SSH 'binding' on the port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are asking two or three questions.

To use ssh to tunnel, I advise you start a non-interactive session

```
ssh -C2qTnN -D 8080 user@IP
```

That will put the ssh tunnel in the background.

Use the proxy: You then configure your browser or system settings to use the proxy on localhost port 8080.

Stop using the proxy: You then re-configure your system to not use the proxy (undo the above step).

To end the ssh session,

```
killall ssh
```

Or kill the process by process id

I usually run a separate ssh session if you wish to enter commands on the server.

See also https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html